# R Shiny Reactive Histogram wrong Input?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that's doing with a `server` and `ui` function like this:

```
df<- read_csv(path_here)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Histograms!"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      checkboxGroupInput("Company", 
                         "Company", 
                         choices = unique(df$Company)
                         ),
      checkboxGroupInput("predicted_condition", 
                         "Predicted Condition", 
                         choices = unique(df$Predicted.Condition)
      )
      ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Histogram ----
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
      
    )
  )
)  
server<- function( input, output, session){
  reactive_data <- reactive({
    df %>% 
      filter(Company %in% input$Company)%>%
      filter(Predicted.Condition %in% input$Predicted_Condition)%>%
      select(Predicted.Probability)
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(reactive_data())
  })
}
```

Basically I'm making a histogram where the user can use check boxes called `Company` and `Predicted_Condition`. Their selections would filter the corresponding columns in my `df`, then I'd make a histogram of the probabilities left in the `Predicted.Probability` column.

However, when I run this I get an error that says `x must be numeric` even though I've checked that the Predicted.Probability column is numeric. Any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: Perhaps you can share some sample data with `dput()` to help you.

Comment: `select` always returns a dataframe, use `pull` to get a vector. Without seeing example data, it's hard to tell where the breaks error comes from

Comment: I ran `dput` on my `Predicted.Probability` column. The last few entries were: `0.000703995, 0.000594523, 0.000214589, 0.000145538, 0.00028317, 
0.000564918, 0.000354667, 0.000280292, 0.000117386, 0.000207468, 
0.000323793, 0.011153646)`

Running summary on the column yields a `min` of `0.0001` and a `max` of `1.0000`, but I'm still getting invalid number of breaks error

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without your data and your ui, but it seems like you are trying to make a histogram from a dataframe. Yes, your column may contain numeric values, but you are essentially filtering down to a dataframe with one column, not a numeric vector.
Try this:

```
server<- function( input, output, session){
  reactive_data <- reactive({
    filtered_dat <- df %>% 
      filter(Company %in% input$Company)%>%
      filter(Predicted.Condition %in% input$Predicted_Condition)

    return(filtered_dat$Predicted.Probability))
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(reactive_data())
  })
}
```

Comment: I've included my `ui` in an edit of the original post. 
I tried your suggestion as well, but now it's giving me an "invalid number of breaks" error. I know for a fact that every entry in the `Predicted.Probability` column is above 0, however. I even tried `return(as.numeric(filtered_dat$Predicted.Probability))` and I still get the breaks error.

Comment: My guess is that your data is not being filtered as you expected. `hist()` will give that error if you supply it with an empty vector or a vector of NA's. For example run:
`x <- integer(0)` `hist(x)` or `x <- rep(NA_integer_, 10)` `hist(x)`
to reproduce that error. If you can't figure out why your data isn't being filtered correctly, copy and paste a `dput()` of your dataframe.

Comment: Double check you're calling the inputs as you defined them in the `inputId` argument too. For example in your question you define an input as `"predicted_condition"` but then later in your `server` say `filter(Predicted.Condition %in% input$Predicted_Condition)` when it should be `input$predicted_condition`